# Java why is the key listener not working?

Tags: java

I do not know why this doesn't work. I have already read many posts, and added setFocusable but it just does not work.

```
public class Spiel {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Playground pg = new Playground();
        pg.setLocation(0,0);
        pg.setSize(1000,1000);
        pg.setVisible(true);
        pg.setFocusable(true);
    }
}



import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Playground extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    Playground(){

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Listener is not attached to any UI items that I can see.  I would not recommend that you do things this way.  Don't extend JFrame; extend JPanel instead.  Keep the Listeners separate and do dependency injection so you can change.

Comment: Thank you. I added addKeyListener(this) and it worked. Ok  so another class with JPanel or no JFrame at all ?

Answer (score 1):

You only implemented the `KeyListener` but if you want it to actually work you still need to register it to your frame.

```
Playground(){
    addKeyListener(this);  // should do the trick
}
```

Otherwise your frame wouldn't know that it actually has to listen and call the methods when a key is pressed.

Comment: sorry, didn't see that you already worked this out. You'll be better of when you listen to the advice of @duffymo :)